# Rails 4 button_to using helper improper redirection

Tags: button, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing

I am building an index for one of my models. Instead of the usual table, I want to have two combo-boxes: one for selecting the object, the other for selecting the method (either edit or destroy). Upon clicking the submit button, I should be redirected to the appropriate method reference (e.g. admin_users/1/edit or admin_users/17/destroy). I have written a helper that constructs the url reference, but for some reason it does not work. when I use button_to I get redirected to the create method, when I use button_tag nothing works. Any ideas?

view code:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
    <h1>Listing admin_users</h1>
    <p><strong>select admin user</strong></p>
    <%= select_tag(@req_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@admin_users, :id, :login)) %>
    <br/>
    <p><strong>select action</strong></p>
    <%= select_tag(@oper, options_for_select([['edit'],['destroy']])) %>
    <br/>
    <%=button_tag 'go go!', get_path(@req_id,@oper) %>
<% end %>
```

helper code:

```
module AdminUsersHelper
    def get_path(req_id,oper)
   a=[req_id, oper].join("/")
   ["admin_users", a].join("/")
  end
end
```

Comment: I've done the same thing in my current rails app. I'll post code tonight. There's no need to use javascript or change your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default method for a form submit is `POST`. You'll need to change the method accordingly.

```
<%= form_tag( '/users/confirm', method: :get ) %>
```

May I suggest submitting with Javascript? You'll have a more dynamic control over the method of the submission. Take a look [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: wouldn't the
`method: :get`
make the destroy method unreachable? (as destroy is associated with the delete http verb)

Comment: Yep then that's why javascript will suite your need better.

Answer (score 0):

so, eventually I went on the javascript solution, just as @Hassanin Ahmed suggested. Thanks for Helping!

```
<%= form_tag('/admin_users', id: "admin_users_menu") do %>
[...]
<font size=4>
    <u>select user:</u>
</font>
<br>
<br>
<select id="admin_user_id" name="admin_user[id]">
  <%= options_for_select @admin_users.collect{|user| [user.login, user.id]} %>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<font size=4> <u>select option:</u></font><br><br>
<input type="radio"  checked name="select_op"  value= "edit" > edit
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio"  name="select_op"   value= "delete" > delete
<br>
<br>
<%= submit_tag "go" %>
<br>
<br>
<% end %>
<script>
$(function (){  
    $("#admin_users_menu").submit(function() {return direct_me() })
})
function direct_me(){
    //getting the admin_user id
    var au_id=$('select').val()
    //getting the desired method
    var op=$('input[name=select_op]:radio:checked').val()
    //making the default url
    var u="admin_users/"+au_id
    var f=$("form")
    if(op=='edit'){
    u=u+"/edit"
    f.attr("method","GET")
}
    else if(op=='delete'){
        f.attr("method","POST")
      f.append("<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='delete'>");
    }
    f.attr("action",u)
    if(op=='delete') return confirm("Are you sure?")
}
</script>
```